# How to fail a Hudson job if a certain string occurs in console output

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

is there a way to make a hudson job fail if a certain string occurs in the console output?

The reason I ask is because we have some jobs that deploy EAR files (via mvn commands) and even though the job runs successfully, I see a string like this:

```
<26-Nov-2010 14:05:32 o'clock CET> <Info> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260121> 
<Initiating undeploy operation for application, legacyservice [archive: null], 
to cde-server-c01 .>

[Deployer:149163]The domain edit lock is owned by another session in non-exclusive 
mode - this deployment operation requires exclusive access to the edit lock 
and hence cannot proceed.
ExitException: status 1
[INFO] Ignore exit
[INFO] Weblogic un-deployment successful
```

I have tried fiddling with the maven command, but it does not really fail. So I wonder, if there was another way to detect this flaw and fail the job.

I imagine failing the job if a string like this occurs:

```
requires exclusive access to the edit lock and hence cannot proceed.
```

I am either interested in a hudson plugin that can do this, or a native way of configure my job for this

Comment: Are you sure that you can't just find a way to disable the ignoring of the exit code?

Comment: No, i am not sure, because i did not figure it out yet. (which means that other tasks were brought to my attention). However, wether it is possible to change exit code of other job or not, is relevant to my particular problem. But I still think the idea of parsing the text has a more general usage beyond my particular problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Log+Parser+Plugin

You can edit the parsing rules file to include any text you want. This should let you use the text `requires exclusive access to the edit lock and hence cannot proceed.` as a regex in the parsing file. The instructions on the wiki page above are quite clear.

Comment: This sounds just like the solution i was looking for. Will accept answer when things are working in our setup. Unfortunately, our (Windows) hudson has a problem finding the log-parser file at: `c:\hudson\log-parser-rules.txt`.

Comment: The rules file has to be on the master. The parsing takes place on it, regardless of the slave.